# How to include Materialize in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, materialize

I first do this on the command line inside my Meteor project:

`meteor npm install --save materialuze-css`

This includes materialize to package.json.

Then, I added this to main.js:

`import M from 'materialize-css';`

But, this does not include the stylesheet to my project.

How to make this work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use SCSS

Materialze is scss based, so you should use the scss compiler (but you are not forced to do, see the section below):

```sh
$ meteor remove standard-minifier-css
$ meteor add fourseven:scss seba:minifiers-autoprefixer
```

You also need to import the scss file:

```js
import M from 'materialize-css';
import 'materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss'
```

#### Use plain css

If you only need the default css and don't intend to customize colors etc.
you may be fine by importing the dist css:

```js
import M from 'materialize-css';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css'
```

No need to use the scss compiler then. Note, that you can safely use the `materialize.css` and don't require the `materialize.min.css` since it will be minified later when your Meteor app build for production using the `standard-minifier-css`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Works nicely.